# Beginner Java Issues

Tags: java

EDIT: I am using BlueJ. When I right click my class I am supposed to enter the values for a and b there rather than the actual code. Is there a way to do that?

Hello I am trying to write a basic program that will let me enter 2 numbers and then automatically calculate the sum, difference, division and remainder, and then print the results to the output. Here is what I have so far. It compiles but I get this error

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at Q1A3.DoTheCalculation(Q1A3.java:33)
at Q1A3.<init>(Q1A3.java:24)
```

when I try to run it. I have no java experience and this is my first time trying anything on the computer other than emailing. Please be gentle! Can you point out my errors and guide me toward fixing them? Thank you.

```
/* 
This program accepts two numbers from the user. Finds out the sum, diff, division and
remainder of the two numbers, and prints the results on the screen 

 */ 
public class Q1A3 
{ 
 //instant variables - replace the example below with your own 
 private int a; 
 private int b; 
 private int sum; 
 private int difference; 
 private int division;
 private int remainder;

 //----------------------------------------- 
 //The following is the constructor that takes the input from the user 
 //and stores it in the system 

 public Q1A3(int a, int b) 
 { 
 DoTheCalculation ( );
 PrintTheResults ( ); 
} 
//------------------------------------------------------------- 
//The following routine does all of the required calculations.
public void DoTheCalculation ( ) 
{ 
sum = (a+b);
difference = (a-b);
division = (a/b);
remainder = (a%b);
}
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 //The following routine prints all of the information including the calculated 
 //items on the screen 

 public void PrintTheResults ( ) 
 { 
 System.out.println("The value of  “a”  is:"); 
 System.out.println("The value of “b” is:"); 
 System.out.println("The sum is:" ); 
 System.out.println("The difference is:"); 
 System.out.println("The division is:"); 
 System.out.println("The remainder is:"); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that creates an instance of your class?

Comment: Well, just make sure b isn't 0.

Comment: Also, in your method "PrintTheResults ( )", do not forget to actually write out the answers! For example: System.out.println("The value of  “a”  is:" + a);  System.out.println("The sum is:" + sum);  the + character here mean string concatenation not arithmetic addition.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem...

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign any values to a or b. try this:

```
 private int a = 5;
 private int b = 7;
```

Comment: I am using BlueJ. When I right click my class I am supposed to enter the values for a and b there rather than in the actual code. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Make sure that private member variables are initialized from constructor parameters.
(2) Make sure to assign variables to string outputs.

Please observe the proposed changes in the following source code:

```
public Q1A3(int a, int b) 
{
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    DoTheCalculation ( );
    PrintTheResults ( ); 
} 

public void PrintTheResults ( ) 
{ 
    System.out.println("The value of  'a'  is:"+a); 
    System.out.println("The value of 'b' is:"+b); 
    System.out.println("The sum is:" +sum); 
    System.out.println("The difference is:"+difference); 
    System.out.println("The division is:"+division); 
    System.out.println("The remainder is:"+remainder);
} 

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Q1A3 obj = new Q1A3(8,4);
}
```

Comment: Now only add a check for `b != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in the first line of the error code "/ by zero". You cannot divide by zero (it'd implode the universe or something.) Try an if statement to test if 0 is being passed, and reject, or skip it.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot divide by zero (it'd implode the universe or something.)

*~ Andrew*

No, it creates black holes. Or something :P

The question has been answered. BUT:

A good way to find the mistake yourself (next time) would have been a good debugger or systematic outputs, e.g. `System.out.println("var a:"+a)` to see what values which variables have at the time, before the error occurs.